# Apex Rest Wrapper - Error Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, webservices, apexrest, null-pointer

So I've done quite a bit of searching on the forum and am learning a ton.  I really appreciate the experts on this forum who are willing to help out.

I am taking inspiration/following the code posted on: https://github.com/sfdcmatt/DF13ApexRest/blob/master/REST_AccountService_V7.cls but am running into an error.

I will be passing in one account and one custom object record. I'm trying to set a look-up field on a record when passing information to create both the account and the custom object.  I'm getting an Error when passing in the params from workbench.

Error: Attempt to de-reference a null object

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v1/application/*')
global class REST_ApplicationService_V1 {  

@HttpPost
  global static PostResponseWrapper doPostMulti(RequestWrapper rqst) {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    PostResponseWrapper response = new PostResponseWrapper();

    try {
        insert rqst.acct;
        response.acct = rqst.acct;

        LLC_BI__Loan__c myLoan = new LLC_BI__Loan__c();   
        myLoan.LLC_BI__Account__r.Id = rqst.acct.Id;
        insert rqst.myLoan;
        response.myLoan = rqst.myLoan;

       //Additional lines etc 
       }
catch(Exception exc) {
        res.StatusCode = 500;
        response.acct = null;
        response.myloan = null;
        response.status = 'Error';
        response.message = 'Your request failed with the following error: ' + exc.getMessage();
    }

    return response;
}
global class RequestWrapper {
    Account acct;
    LLC_BI__Loan__c myLoan;       
}

global class PostResponseWrapper {
    Account acct;
    LLC_BI__Loan__c myLoan;
    String status;
    String message;

    public PostResponseWrapper(){
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a line number? Can you tell us which line is actually throwing the error?

Comment: I don't get an error in the Developer Console, however, when I try and input data via workbench I get the error message:   "message" : "Your request failed with the following error: Attempt to de-reference a null object", I'm pretty sure it has to with the setting of the variable myLoan.

Comment: Best (for debugging purposes) to append `exc.getStackTraceString()` as well as `exc.getMessage()` so you get line numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reference field like:

```
myLoan.LLC_BI__Account__r
```

is only populated when the two objects are queried together; in your code that reference will be null and so a likely source of the error.

Replace these lines:

```
    LLC_BI__Loan__c myLoan = new LLC_BI__Loan__c();   
    myLoan.LLC_BI__Account__r.Id = rqst.acct.Id;
    insert rqst.myLoan;
```

with:

```
    rqst.myLoan.LLC_BI__Account__c = rqst.acct.Id;
    insert rqst.myLoan;
```

which is the conventional way of relating two objects, where you set the foreign key ID field to the related objects's ID. This assumed both the `Account` and `LLC_BI__Loan__c` are set by the caller in the request.

Comment: Um, you seem to have removed the object instantiation in your replacement block.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The question says both object are passed into the REST method; in any case the local variable `myLoan` was not being inserted or otherwise used.

Comment: Ah gotcha. It's a little confusing to look at but it makes sense now.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I don't have enough reputation to up-vote yet, but that fixed the issue.

Comment: @StarleyFlynn - but you can mark the answer as the solution , I'm sure Keith and the Community will appreciate it.